# How to check if IPv6 is enabled on a Debian Linux?

Tags: debian, ipv6

Can one disable the IPv6 stack on Debian Linux, especially Wheezy? If so how do I know if it's disabled on a system?

Answer (score 10):

To check if IPv6 is disabled through `sysctl` :

```
sysctl -a|grep disable_ipv6
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can:

```
echo net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1  > /etc/sysctl.d/disableipv6.conf 
sysctl --system
```

But you might need to do several other things, as described in the [related article in the Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6). The description for squeeze should still be valid for Wheezy.